# QGIS - points at the North and South Pole disappear in the composer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, print-composer, antarctica, arctic

I am using QGIS 3.4 to produce maps of the Arctic and Antarctic with weighted points from a csv file. 
I noticed that I lose the points at the North and South Pole when I add the map in the composer. They are present on the map, they just disappear in the composer (see pictures below). 
Is there a way to avoid this?

The map in QGIS:
[image: how it looks like on the base map in QGIS]

The map in QGIS's composer:
[image]

(in case you were wondering: I change the projection when making maps of the Antarctic. Projections used are Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area for the North and South Pole. I tried playing with other pole-centered projections and the problem remained)

Comment: I was going to suggest offsetting any points exactly at the pole by a fraction of a degree of latitude, but when I used Google Maps to double-check the actual coordinates of the North Pole, it got very squirrelly when I tried to find coordinates for any point above 85 degrees latitude. What CRS is the point layer in? If it's not in one of the pole projections, I suggest exporting the pole-centered data to a separate layer in the relevant pole projection.